# Phonegap Ajax request.responseText empty, trying to get a csv file from a yahoo stock info link

Tags: ajax, csv, cordova, xmlhttprequest, yahoo

I'm developing an app using only html, javascript and css because I'm making it for phonegap (so no php or anything like that). I am trying to develop a simple stock quotes application that uses the yahoo stock csv api.

This api works by providing it the symbol of any given stock and it will download a csv file that gives you information about the stock.

An example would be if you look up info about Tesla Motors, its stock symbol is TSLA, and you would use the following link:

```
[http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=TSLA&f=nsl1op&e=.csv][1]
```

Going to this link manually, will automatically download the csv file with the info on Tesla Motors, so the file contents would look something like this:

```
"Tesla Motors, Inc","TSLA",84.35,81.23,83.24
```

But when I try to get it in my app, it returns an empty response. Here is how I try to get the info:

```
function getStockInfo(stockSymbol) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + stockSymbol + "&f=nsl1op&e=.csv", true);
    request.send();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0) {
                alert("response: " + request.responseText);
                var stockInfo = request.responseText.split(",");

                localStorage.companyName = stockInfo[0];
                localStorage.stockSymbol = stockInfo[1];
                localStorage.startPrice = stockInfo[2];
                localStorage.endPrice = stockInfo[3];
                localStorage.highPrice = stockInfo[4];
                document.location.href = "stockInfo.html";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The line that says `alert("response: " + request.responseText);` shows the request.responseText is blank. Am I doing this wrong? If it's a link that downloads a csv file, do you have to get the request differently? Is there a special way of doing this for phonegap?, I've been trying to find the answer on this, but haven't managed to. I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you watch the console, you will see the following error :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=TSLA&f=nsl1op&e=.csv.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

You have to allow the access to the yahoo server. In config.xml add the line

`<access origin="*" />` if you want to allow access to any server or

or `<access origin=http://download.finance.yahoo.com" />` if you only want to allow access to the yahoo server

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide

Comment: Thankyou. I later figured that out and got it working on my android phone. But I still haven't gotten working on a pc. Is there a way to whitelist the service for Windows 7 or other non mobile platforms?

Comment: you could either try to disable security settings in your browser or use a local php or something page on your pc to access the yahoo server