# how to get a .csv file from www folder in my phonegap application?

Tags: android, jquery, csv, cordova, android-assets

Here I am using .CSV file in phonegap application for one application.

I have 25 .CSV files.

I want to get full all 25 .CSVs in my application.

[I tried this link](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-csv/)

for my reference but it takes from input.
i dont want to get file from user input. i want to get file directly from www folder.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (isAPIAvailable()) {
        $('#files').bind('change', handleFileSelect);
    }
});

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    //var files = new array['C:\Users\Bhavdip Bhalodia\Desktop\raw\bc.csv'];
    var file = "C:\Users\Bhavdip Bhalodia\Desktop\raw\bc.csv";
    alert("file" + file);
    // read the file metadata
    var output = ''
    output += '<span style="font-weight:bold;">' + escape(file.name) + '</span><br />\n';
    output += ' - FileType: ' + (file.type || 'n/a') + '<br />\n';
    output += ' - FileSize: ' + file.size + ' bytes<br />\n';
    output += ' - LastModified: ' + (file.lastModifiedDate ? file.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a') + '<br />\n';
    // read the file contents
    printTable(file);
    // post the results
    $('#list').append(output);
}

function printTable(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        var csv = event.target.result;
        var data = $.csv.toArrays(csv);
        var html = '';
        for (var row in data) {
            html += '<tr>\r\n';
            for (var item in data[row]) {
                html += '<td>' + data[row][item] + '</td>\r\n';
            }
            html += '</tr>\r\n';
        }
        $('#contents').html(html);
    };
    reader.onerror = function () {
        alert('Unable to read ' + file.fileName);
    };
}
```

**UPDATE**
I dont want to read CSV manual change we want to take file from the path. without user prompting input.

In this example, input taking from user but i dont want.
**[I went here also:](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)**

Thanks and sorry for my Grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is under the www folder of your app You should just be able to load the contents using an "AJAX" fetch even though it is bundled in the app.

```
$.get('js/filename.ext');
```

Comment: can you give me some more code so i can understand, 
I am new in this. Because i have tried **$.get(url,function(){...})** but it was not working.

I have 20 CSV file to read.

A small example will be appreciable.

Comment: check out this link :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238139/phonegap-ajax-request-responsetext-empty-trying-to-get-a-csv-file-from-a-yahoo